# Is the 'convert' tag useful?

Tags: discussion, tags

Looking at the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag makes me wonder what kind of user would be tracking and using it?

Clicking on the tag doesn't reveal much information either:

> The convert tag has no usage guidance, can you help us create it?

It appears to be mostly used for questions about 'converting' a piece of code from one programming language into another. It is also used when discussing converting data types, within the same language.

This to me seems like a really generic use case for a tag, and doesn't appear to be bringing much value as a tag.

A lot of the questions with this tag tend to have multiple, more relevant tags, such as the programming language they are converting from and to. In addition, they seem to be low scoring questions.

It has 28 followers, and 194 tagged questions at this moment.

Would the [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/convert) tag be a good candidate for removal, or clarifying?

Comment: I have a proposal to remove this tag [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355395/lets-convert-this-to-a-better-tag).